# Is there a reason to specify DEFAULT (NULL) on a nullable column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table created like this originally:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XX (
YY int DEFAULT(NULL)
)
```

If you do this, and then script the table later on, you will get the following code, plus a randomly named default constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].XX([YY] [int] NULL) 
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].XX ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [YY]
GO
```

Now is there any real point in specifying `DEFAULT (NULL)` on a column instead of just leaving it as `[YY] [int] NULL` in the first place?

Comment: No point in any database I'm familiar with.

Comment: On second thought, although it doesn't change the way the data will be added, I guess it could be considered an expression of design intent ("I intend for this column to be added as NULL, I didn't forget to set a default") which makes the design of the database clearer to the next person to come along.

Comment: Next (related) question: is there any pint in specifying `NULL` on a column instead of just leaving it as `[yy] [INTEGER]` in the first place?

Comment: Yes, there is a point in specifying NULL after the data type for nullable columns. The server or database may have different defaults set re: NULL than what you've assumed. Also it just makes it more clear what your intention was.

Answer (score 34):

There is no need to add a `DEFAULT(NULL)` to nullable columns.

If data is not supplied to such columns, they will have a `NULL`.

The only benefit I see is the one [Larry Lustig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180368/larry-lustig) has posted in his comment to the question - it documents the fact that you have not forgotten to add a default to the nullable column.

Comment: Default constraint needs to be dropped first before the column is dropped

Answer (score 8):

None that I can think of.

From a programming point of view `NULL` is the implicit default anyway without needing to (implicitly) create an actual default constraint in `sys.objects`.

Both of the following will end up inserting `NULL` without the default constraint.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].XX([YY])  VALUES (DEFAULT)

INSERT INTO [dbo].XX([YY])  DEFAULT VALUES
```

I don't subscribe to the view in the comments that it documents you didn't "forget" to add a default constraint. Nullable columns rarely have default constraints in my experience so this would just add a load of unneeded clutter.

The more important thing to include is the column nullability - as below - so it is clear to future readers that the column is nullable and so it doesn't depend on `ANSI_NULL_DFLT` session options what you actually end up with.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.XX (
YY int NULL
)
```